# Flip a DIV onclick

Tags: jquery

I'm using the [Flip!](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) plugin to flip a div on click and revert the flip when a user clicks the div again. The code below makes the DIV flip but does not flip it back when you click it again.

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
$("#flipbox").bind("click",function(){
    $("#flipbox").flip({
        direction:'rl',
        content:'this is my new content',
        onEnd: function(){
            $("#flipbox").bind("click",function(){
                $("#flipbox").revertFlip(); 
            });
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

});

HTML

```
<div id="flipbox">
    Hello! I'm a flip-box! :)
</div>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to unbind the existing click handler before adding the new one. Add `unbind("click")` to the method chain before adding the revert click handler.

Comment: Well, if you simply add another listener to `#flipbox` each time the animation ends, I am pretty sure you will end up with multiple listeners on the same item and they will conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting the state of the flipbox onto the element, I used an if statement to check that state and determine how to flip the box.

JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/HP7mu/
**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
$("#flipbox").bind("click",function(){
    if($(this).data('flipped')!="yes"){
    $("#flipbox").flip({
        direction:'rl',
        content:'this is my new content',
        onEnd: function(){
                $("#flipbox").data('flipped','yes');
        }
    });
    }else{
        $("#flipbox").flip({
        direction:'rl',
        content:'Hello! I\'m a flip-box! :)',
        onEnd: function(){
                $("#flipbox").data('flipped','no');
        }
    });
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

**Html**: Same
*Note: As demonstrated in the comments below Asad has an even better solution to this by simply using `revertFlip` to revert the state if the `else` is triggered in the code.*

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the note. Calling `revertFlip` works fine, as demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2sva/)

Comment: Hmm, it has worked for you. When I implemented the revertFlip in the "onEnd", it didn't work. Perhaps the "onEnd" is triggered before the data for the revertFlip is implemented? Anyhow, thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the post to point out that you have a better implementation

Comment: How doI modify this code if one side of the DIV is a big image and the other side text with links? Can content: contain a path to the image?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to do. Thanks for your help.